# How to access a folder in sandboxed backend if the folder was opened in sandboxed frontend

Tags: macos, sandbox

I develop MacOS applications that should work in sandbox:
1. Frontend application with UI where user can open a folder that should be used to save files by the backend.
2. Backend application can be run any time and should save files into the folder user specified in the frontend.
I can store access to the folder in the frontend by using security scoped bookmark and pass this bookmark to the backend, but I cannot access the folder in backend. The backend is placed inside frontend's bundle. Both applications can be in the same app group.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Nope, the backend can be launched by user via custom URL sheme.

Comment: Well I think XPC will solve your issue.

Comment: I need to configure backend in frontend. What XPC service I should create? If I replace backend by XPC service then I cannot run it without frontend. But I want to run the backend independently from frontend...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the details (else I would have answered more formally) but I understand that XPC is the mechanism used for this type of thing.